# Return string if two conditions are met - one being match and one being null in same row

Tags: excel, if-statement, match

I have a resource library. We are manually managing who has checked out the resources and when they are returned. I have two worksheets in my workbook.

1) With a list of all the resources available

2) An ongoing list of which resources are checked out, by whom, when, and when they are returned

On the first worksheet I want to identify if a resource is currently checked out automatically. This is determined by locating the resource ID in the borrowed resources worksheet, and also identifying that the checked in column is null.

I believe I need to use a combination of if, and, and match, but I can't quite get it. Part of the issue is that the ID number will appear multiple times since the resource will be checked in and out by multiple people over time, so the search can't stop at the first row in which that matches. It has to look through all rows for both the ID number and the null value, and if it finds the combination anywhere within the worksheet, it should return "Yes" in the resource list worksheet.

Comment: Try using the CountIfs function to look for your two criteria. If the result is 0, then it's not found, if it is >=1 then the match is found. Would that work?

Comment: Thanks, @DavidZemens. I was able to use the COUNTIFS as the logical test, and then add user friendly text to indicate if the resource was checked out or not.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the answer to this question using David's `COUNTIFS` suggestion. I nested the `COUNTIFS` in an IF as part of the criteria for the logical test. A value greater than 0 is applied if both the resource is found and the date returned is blank. So if the value returned is greater than 0, "Checked Out" is displayed. If not, "Available" is displayed.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet1!A3,Sheet2!$H:$H,"")>0,"Checked Out","Available")
```

This works even if the resource appears multiple times.